# How do you force Blazor to obey dynamic CSS rules?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I have a bit of HTM like this:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <NavLink class="@(home ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link")" 
             aria-current="page" 
             href="/">Home</NavLink>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <NavLink class="@(blog ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link")" 
             aria-current="page" 
             href="/blog">Blog</NavLink>
</li>
```

and a bit of code as such:

```cs
bool home = false;
bool blog = false;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (MyNavigationManager.Uri.Equals("http://abc.xzy/"))
        home = true;
    else if (MyNavigationManager.Uri.Contains("http://abc.xzy/blog"))
        blog = true;
    Console.WriteLine($"home: {home}");
    Console.WriteLine($"blog: {blog}");
}
```

The "Blog" anchor tag obeys the CSS rule. When the url contains "blog", it's bold and when it doesn't contain "blog", it's normal as expected.
The "Home" anchor tag on the other hand doesn't seem to care what page I'm on, it's always bold.
I printed out the values of home and blog to sure and as expected, when I'm on the /blog page:

```
home: false
blog: true
```

but the "Home" anchor tag is always bold.
I noticed that if I change the href of the "Home" anchor tag to something else, anything else e.g.

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <NavLink class="@(home ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link")" 
             aria-current="page" 
             href="/anythingelse">Home</NavLink>
</li>
```

it stops being bold but it also never becomes bold when I'm on the homepage.
How do I fix this issue?
Edit: I'm using Blazor Auto (Server and Webassembly) mode and on .net8
Here is a link to what the config looks like on imgur: https://i.imgur.com/1I5g4dZ.png

My App.razor file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/webp" href="icon.webp" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveAuto" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveAuto" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is my App.razor file has this in it:
<head>
    ...
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveAuto" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveAuto" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
...

Comment: This is what the config looks like: https://i.imgur.com/1I5g4dZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic duplicates (and conflicts with) the built-in higlighting of NavLink.

You'll probably get closer when you add  `Match="NavLinkMatch.All"` to the Home link:

```html
  <NavLink class="@(home ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link")" 
             aria-current="page" 
             Match="NavLinkMatch.All"
             href="/">Home</NavLink>
```

The default for NavLinkMatch is Prefix and then `href="/"` matches all URLs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know NavLink did extra things. I'm coming from Nuxt so I'm used to NuxtLink only handling navigation. I read more about NavLinks and realized I could remove the logic I wrote and just place Match="NavLinkMatch.All" for Home and Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" for Blog and it works like a dream now. Thank you so much.